# Firebase Cloud Messaging Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send cloud messages (push notifications) from the firebase console to my app. I have seen similar questions on here but nothing worked for me.
I followed the documentation, watched the tutorial, searched online, and StackOverflow and nothing seems to work for me. MainActivity, I am getting the token and trying to use it to send a test message.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.exception)
                    return@OnCompleteListener
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                val token = task.result?.token

                // Log and toast
                val msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token)
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            })
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService similar to the code from the documenttaion

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        Log.e(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                scheduleJob()
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow()
            }
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")

            sendNotification(it.body.toString())
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START on_new_token]
    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

    /**
     * Schedule async work using WorkManager.
     */
    private fun scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkerActivity::class.java).build()
        WorkManager.getInstance().beginWith(work).enqueue()
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private fun handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.")
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private fun sendRegistrationToServer(token: String?) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
        Log.d(TAG, "sendRegistrationTokenToServer($token)")
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_sample_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    companion object {

        private const val TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService"
    }
}
```

And inside my AndroidManifest file I have this

```
<!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service
            android:name=".ui.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
```

I saw a similar question that had an answer to downgrading the firebase messaging dependency, I also tried that with no luck. I will post more If I have to. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to retype my Service in order for it to work. I have to remember not to copy and paste any more. Going to leave it here for anybody who faces this problem in the future. Happy coding!

```
class FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    val TAG = "FCMService"

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        Log.d(TAG,"From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")

            if (true) {
                scheduleJob()
            }else {
                handleNow()
            }
        }

        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message notification body: ${it.body}")

            sendNotification(it.body.toString())
        }

    }

    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this, channelId
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_sample_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())

    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        //super.onNewToken(token)

        Log.d(TAG, token)
    }

    private fun handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task done")
    }

    private fun scheduleJob() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


}
```

```
<service
            android:name=".ui.services.FCMService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
```

Answer (score 2):

First just make sure that testing notification works,inside onNewToken place just log the token and try to send it manually, make sure that your software accept/receive notification while on background.( open up Settings and go to Apps & Notifications. Within that screen, tap on See all X apps (where X is the number of apps you have installed) then select yours and make sure that "background activity" is on.
Try this out also,It works for me.I hope it could help
dependency : `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'`

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "msg received: ${remoteMessage.from}")
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title, remoteMessage.notification?.body)
        }
    }
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Refreshed token: $token")
    }
    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Comment: If your device is Huawei check this https://www.itechify.com/2016/02/01/how-to-fix-missing-push-notifications-on-huawei-smartphones/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try what you said and ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions with no luck and I can't find option "Background Activity". I am using a OnePlus 5t mobile phone if that helps.

Comment: background activity in samsung devices,So check this https://www.itechify.com/2016/02/01/how-to-fix-missing-push-notifications-on-huawei-smartphones/

Comment: I can't find it but everything looks ok in my settings. I think it might be something I'm missing. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: Turns out I had to retype my Service file for it to work. I posted it below. I will upvote your answer as you were willing to help. Thanks again for your time.